# How to determine what part of the file was modified out-of-process? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, file, indexing, filesystemwatcher

I'm writing a system for indexing the contents of files. The system monitors changes in files through the `FileSystemWatcher` and, by event, starts the process of updating the index.

Obviously, if file was changed, re-index whole file is bad solution, because the file can be large. It is necessary that the time spent for re-indexing depends on the number of changes and not on the file size.

The question is how quickly to determine what part of the file was changed?
 Calculating the diff between file versions is too resource-intensive.

I thought to do as follows:

1. Split the file into parts by size of few kilobytes
2. Calculate the digests (hashes) from each of the parts (SHA-1 or MD5)
3. On the file change event quickly compare the digests of each part of
   the file
4. Re-index only the changed parts of the file.

There are 2 problems here:

1. The changed part (`#N`) may contain shifts. These shifts affect the
   parts `#N+1`, `#N+2`, etc. This means that I will get other hashes
   for all these parts. If file was changed at the beginning, whole
   file will be re-indexed.
2. Hash functions give collisions, and therefore there is no guarantee
   that the coincidence of the digests means that the original data has
   not been changed.

Are there any ideas how this can be done at its best?
Maybe there is a way to get the modified file system pages of the file?

Comment: On a file changed event, how can you tell what the change is in any manner?  Do you have a previous copy stored somewhere?  If so, how do you get that copy?  How do you ensure it's a coherent copy that you didn't make while the file was in the middle of being changed?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Instance of `FileSystemWatcher ` fires event when file changed. The system stores direct index for file, so I have a kind of copy. The index is updated by a timer with a small time interval for the collected changes. The question is how to collect changes?
I don't need an instant update of the index, but it should be fast enough.

Comment: Assuming the "kind of a copy" you mention is the result of indexing the document, it seems the only way you can tell what's changed is to index the changed document.

Comment: Indexing process consist of building two kind of indices: direct and inverted. Inverted index is used for searching. Direct index is used for removing keys from inverted index. When file changed I need to update indices for actual file content. If I will calculate full diff between actual file and stored copy (in direct index), than I should be spent O(n) of time for lookup file. It seems in this case it is easier to re-index the entire file.

Comment: *It seems in this case it is easier to re-index the entire file.*  From your description of the process, I agree.  You have to do some significant comparison just to find the differences in the first place, and those comparisons seem about as resource-intensive as just indexing the entire document.